# How to create Local Data Caching in c# WinApps?

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

Anyone can give me an example on how to create local data caching? Like for example I query 10 millions records from my DB and I want to store it in my local so that I would not encounter performance problem next time when I want to reload the data. Thank you so much.

Comment: Do you want your cache to be locally persistent?

Comment: Hi Oded, once the user exiting on the application it should be erase or delete. Any idea? or sample code on data caching?

Comment: @David Stratton  - you're right dude why would you waste your time if you really don't know the answer on this post, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `static List<T>` where T is your entity..

Comment: A good approach not requiring a heavy dataset, though an `IDictionary` with a unique object key is usually quite efficient and still consumes a lot less memory than a `DataSet`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you only want a cache during the lifetime of the application, you can use a DataSet for this purpose (assuming you have enough memory). Just read one into the DataSet and from then on only ever read from it:

```
DataSet myData = null;

public DataSet GetMyData()
{
   if (myData == null)
   {
      myData = GetDataFromDatabase();
   }
   return myData;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Oded, Is dataset can handled 10 Millions of records? I tried using it but the problem is on Searching & Filtering of Records. The issue is the performance.

Comment: @kurt_jackson19 - Why can't you defer searching and filtering to the database? This is what databases are good for.

Comment: @Oded , yeah i understand, the problem is it takes time before you can get the output. Assuming that you have 10Millions of records.

Comment: @kurt_jackson19 - with good indexing, a database server will not have a problem filtering/searching on 10 million records. The data transfer will of course take time, but one hopes you do not need all 10 million records in one go.

Comment: @oded, thanks you. That's why i'm looking for alternate solution.

Comment: @kurt_jackson19 - You may need to rethink your application architecture. I don't know your requirements and what it does, so can't really comment further.